# mongo - find items who at least match an array of values

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

database entries:

```
{"item1": ["a", "b"], "item2":"etc"}
{"item1": ["a", "b", "c"], "item2":"etc"}
{"item1": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], "item2":"etc"}
```

I want to return all entries, where `a`, `b` and `c` are in the item1 array. It can have additional values.

The `{"item1": {"$in" :["a", "b", "c"]}}` query returns if any of the array items are found, which is not ideal.

Is there an easier way to do this, other than nesting `$in` statements inside an `$and` block:

```
{"item1": {"$and" :[
    {"$in" :["a"]},
    {"$in" :["b"]},
    {"$in" :["c"]},
]}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `$in`

```
for item in col.find({"$and": [{"item1": 'a', "item1": 'b', "item1": 'c'}]}):
    print(item)
```

**Output**

```
{'_id': ObjectId('54fa181014d995a397252a1a'), 'item1': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

You could also use aggregation pipelines and the [**$setIsSubset**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#exp._S_setIsSubset) operator.

```
col.aggregate([{"$project": { "item1": 1, "is_subset": { "$setIsSubset": [ ['a', 'b', 'c'], "$item1" ] }}},{"$match": {"is_subset": True}}])
```

**Output**

```
{
    'ok': 1.0,
    'result': [
                  {
                      '_id': ObjectId('54fa181014d995a397252a1a'), 
                      'item1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
                      'is_subset': True
                   }
               ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this racks up speedwise with respect to pymongo operations, but you could always do the following...

```
s = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
[e for e in entries if set(e['item1']).issubset(s)]
```